# Why is this code showing $req variable undefined?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, inner-join, query-builder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class universityController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function getStudents(Request $req)
    {
        $students= DB::table('students')
        ->join('applicants', function ($join) {
            $join->on('students.id', '=', 'applicants.studentid')
                 ->where('applicants.scholarshipid','=', $req->scholarshipid);
        })
        ->get();
        return $students;
        // return $req->scholarshipid;
    }
}
```

Comment: because it isn't in the scope of that anonymous function, you have to tell the anonymous function to use variables from the parent scope

Comment: How to tell that one ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php  Example #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@lagbox** mention, you are in an anonymous function and it can't reach the outer scope
so to fix this problem you need to use `use` like this

```
 public function getStudents(Request $req)
    {
        $students= DB::table('students')
        ->join('applicants', function ($join) use($req) {
            $join->on('students.id', '=', 'applicants.studentid')
                 ->where('applicants.scholarshipid','=', $req->scholarshipid);
        })
        ->get();
        return $students;
        // return $req->scholarshipid;
    }
```

for more info about `anonymous function` check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) here

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous variable

```
$students= DB::table('students')
        ->join('applicants', function ($join) use ($req) {
            $join->on('students.id', '=', 'applicants.studentid')
                 ->where('applicants.scholarshipid','=', $req->scholarshipid);
        })
        ->get();
```

for more
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php